# using files stored in the SDCard as resourses for internal website on a Browser

Tags: android

I need to download some resources from the net, then locally process them and show them on a BrowserActivity.

Since the resources (images) could be really big I'm saving them in the SDCard.

1. How may I refer to those stored resources from an html page? The html page is embedded into my app (It's in assets folder). I think this will fire some kind of security issues.
2. Is this the right approach? or is there any better solution?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for question 1): You can refer to file on your sd card using "file://" prefix. See example below:

```
String fileName = "x"; // here is the file name of the downloaded image

String imagePath = "file://" + getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath(fileName.getAbsolutePath();    

String html = html+"<img src=\"" + imagePath + "\"/>" // embed that code in your modified html source.
```